# exec multiThread for one process - java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem, like this :

I have an array with 50 elements, i'd like calculate with each element, for faster, how do devide for 5 threads, each thread handling and calculate for 10 elements, and not duplicate with orther threads.

And remember number of thread like a variable, maybe 5 or 10 or any number.
I try use like :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){  //mycalculate }
```

but all of 5 threads just process 10 elements first.

Anyone can help me ! please.

(Hope you understand my question, my English not good)

Thanks

Comment: Add some more code, how you create threads, passing input to them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {  
    int final taskNo = i;
    executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           // perform 'mycalculate' for task 'taskNo'
        }
    });
}
```

(That can be written more neatly using lambdas, but lets stick with the "classic Java" way for now.)

This does not deal with the issue of how to wait for the tasks to finish.  For that, you could capture the `Future` objects that `submit` returns, and call `get` on each one.

It also doesn't deal with any synchronization that would be necessary if the tasks changed any shared objects.

> i'd like calculate with each element, for faster ...

If the 'mycalculate' task is lengthy, and the tasks don't interfere with each other, and you have multiple cores, this approach should give some speedup.

Comment: Thank you so much, Stephen.. Sorry i can't vote for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try parallel stream like this.

```
SomeClass[] array = new SomeClass[50];
// fill array
Stream.of(array)
    .parallel()
    .forEach(e -> /* calculate */);
```